# Python replace text BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with this bit of python. It works but if any of the data contains a comma it obviously messes up my CSV.

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get(sys.argv[1])

html = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html.parser')

for br in html.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with(" ")

for tr in html.find_all('tr'):
    data = []   

    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        data.append(td.text.strip())

    if data:
        print("{}".format(','.join(data)))
```

Is it possible to replace commas with spaces?

Example, from...

```
column 1    column 2    column,3    column 4
```

To...

```
column 1,column 2,column 3,column 4
```

At the moment I get this which is causing issues...

```
column 1,column 2,column,3,column 4
```

Comment: Did you try to replace the comma with space before appending to data? `data.append(td.text.strip().replace(',', ' '))`

Comment: It is working as expected. your input is `column 1    column 2    column,3    column 4` so it will return accordingly `column 1,column 2,column,3,column 4`
Because you're having `,` by default after column 3

Comment: `import re`, then just do  `yourformattedData = re.findall(r"[\w]+\s[\d]")`. `for data in yourformattedData: output.append(data + ",")`

Comment: Thanks @KeyurPotdar that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try `data.append(td.text.strip().replace(',', ' ')`